# How to have 2 of the SAME angular apps running on the same page?

Tags: angular

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <container-app-root>
        <app-root></app-root>
        <app-root></app-root>
      </container-app-root>
  </body>
</html>
```

> I'm trying to run two of the same angular apps from within another
>   containing angular app. The containing angular app boostraps but only
>   one of the inner angular apps bootstraps. The other one is just
>   treated as regular html tags. I get no errors.
>
> This is not my setup but instead just a simple setup of what I would
>   like to be able to do.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure the use case for this, but you might be better off creating one master app with 2 child apps inside

Comment: @chrismclarke wouldn't that be the same issue? As in, I would need the child apps to be the same app.

Comment: it's a similar issue you're right, but by having them both imported into a parent app you can have more flexibility over forRoot/forChild style methods and the bootstrapping process

Answer (score 1):

So the fact that they are the same makes no difference, the challenge is running two angular apps on the same page. This by default isn't supported, with whichever script loads first taking control of the page and loading the app (and blocking the other).

Depending on the use case, it would be recommended to turn the 'app' into a component or module that could have multiple copies embedded in a regular app.

If however, you require a solution with two apps on the same page, here is an "app of apps" example stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/github/mpierce5/angular-app-of-apps

Discussion of the techniques involved in combining multiple apps can be found at the following links:

https://medium.com/swlh/multiple-angular-apps-on-a-single-page-9f49bc863177

https://medium.com/disney-streaming/combining-multiple-angular-applications-into-a-single-one-e87d530d6527

Comment: These were the types of articles I had found when searching.. they are still talking about two separate angular apps running on the same page, which isn't an issue for me. I am needing to run two of the same angular apps (same root `AppModule`)

Comment: As you won't be able to bootstrap both app modules at the same time that won't be possible, instead you need a third app which can be bootstrapped with two copies of the first app embedded inside

Comment: But as suggested in my comment and above, a much simpler solution would be to try and isolate all the app functionality in a component/provider module which can then be loaded twice into the app if that's possible

Comment: Would you mind throwing an example of for this? I think I understand the structure like:

`container
  same-app
  same-app
container`

But i'm not sure how these would be bootstrapped

Comment: which example? the 3 app case or the component/provider module case?

Comment: 3 app case, if you didnt mind. I wanted to keep a simpler example, but the 3 app case is actually my structure for my real application. I have a outer containing angular app which can contain x number of child angular apps. All of those child angular apps being the same angular app, and those are the ones that only have the 1st one actually bootstrapping

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/github/mpierce5/angular-app-of-apps
Will add to the answer also

Comment: This isn't quite what I was looking for.. is there a way to do it without using routing? I'm wanting the ability to interact with the same application and have each `view` showing on the same page. The link is also two separate app modules, but when trying to just copy and paste the app1 route, it seems to work. But again routing isn't what I was looking for. It's the ability to have multiple root tags of the same app on one page and could be interacted with at the same time

Answer (score 0):

You can build the functionality into a component the provides all the services that should be unique instances. Then when you have that component on a page twice the data from one will be unique to each and they wont interfere with each other.